# Hibernate Projections.min() returned multiple rows

Tags: java, hibernate, null, projection, min

I am trying to get the minimum value of a column in a table. This sounds trivial but I experience problems (I am using **MySql 5.1 database**).

The situation is a little complicated.
We have an interface which is implemented from two classes.
Each one these two classes is extended from another three classes. 
Each two of these three extendors have hibernate mapping (the base classes also have mapping) => so we have
Interface I implemented by

> classA(mapped) extended by classA1(mapped) , classA2(mapped) ,
>   classA3(not mapped) classB(mapped) extended by classB1(mapped) ,
>   classB2(mapped) , classB3(not mapped)

Here is the problem with an example code:

```
Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(samplesType)
    .setProjection(Projections.min("pollingTime"));
List resultList= c.list()`enter code here`;
```

After the *.list()* is executed there are three values in the resultList:
First is null, Second is null, Third contains the correct minimum value I'm looking for.

I was using `c.uniqueResult()` but it "returns"

> org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique
>   result: 3

I've also tried to use hibernate's

```
createQuery(select min(pollingTime) from tableName).list()
```

but the result is the same (two nulls and one with the correct result).

I've also tried to add a predefined ResultTransformer to remove the null values from the list but I've failed.

As a workaround I can get the required minimum value using sql query:

```
createSQLQuery("SELECT MIN(pool_time) FROM tableName")
```

which is the only solution for the moment.

Do you have any ideas why the returned result is not correct?

Regards,
Niki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason for this nulls returned.
As I described there is some inheritance in the system.
So, while searching for the minimum value in the base class table, hibernate tries to find the minimums for all the subclasses tables. 
In our case the tables of the subclasses are empty so there is no minimum, therefore it founds the correct value together with the null values from the subclasses tables.

As a solution to the problem I set the polymorphism to explicit in the hibernate mapping file:

```
<class name="class" table="TABLE" polymorphism="explicit">
```

The above disables searching in the specified table while searching a superclass table.

Niki

Answer (score 2):

Rather than focusing on removing the `null`s from the list, I think you should figure out where they are coming from.  I wonder, do you have table rows where the value of that column is `NULL`?  Perhaps you should try something like:

```
    select min(r.pollingTime) from r : tableName where r.pollingTime != NULL
```

Comment: In fact this is one of the first things I've checked directly with MySQL Query Browser. There are no any null values in this column.

This is a good point taking into account that this column is not unique key and is not set as not null-able.


Niki

Edit: I also agree that it's better to find out why I get null values rather than finding a way to filter them from the result.

Comment: I've also tried the following code. 


String qryStr = "select min(tn.pollingTime) from " + tableName 
    + " tn where tn.pollingTime != NULL";
List resultList = getSession().createQuery(qryStr).list();

The result in the list is now reversed:
minValue, null, null.

It looks that as soon as I use hibernate (query, creteria, projection etc.) for this task it returns wrong results.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your data type, min value for a integer and String may be different. For example, 1, 2, 11 if taken as a integer 11 is max. But if taken as a string 2 is max.

Verify what is the data type of the column.

Comment: The data type is long in all the mapping files. It contains the time in milliseconds stored in long in the classes and the db (as per defined in the hibernate mapping).